# Cypher Traverse tree in single query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Assume you have following layout.  A root node known as a "group" that can be found by the following:

```
MATCH (g: Group {key: $groupKey}) RETURN g;
```

And a series of Messages owned by the group:

```
MATCH (g: Group {key: $groupKey})-[r: Owns]->(m: Message) RETURN m;
```

And each message can have many replies also represented as messages

```
MATCH (m: Message {key: $messageKey})-[r: Owns]->(reply: Message) RETURN reply;
```

The question is how in a single query do you traverse from g to retrieve the graph of all messages and their replies.  Assume no circular paths exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return every `Message` in the tree rooted at `g`.

```
MATCH (g:Group {key: $groupKey})-[:Owns*]->(m:Message)
RETURN g, COLLECT(DISTINCT m) AS messages;
```